# Repeated array sampling yields duplicates. Why? (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, duplicates, shuffle, sample

In Ruby:

I sample element from array. I see duplicate (same element) every 30 samples or so. Sometimes as close as 5-6 samples apart. Why?

This is my code:

```
some_array = IO.readlines("file with 5000 unique elements")

some_array.shuffle!

@random_element = some_array.sample

puts @random_element
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want n random non-duplicate elements from your array, you should call `some_array.sample(n)`.

Sample doesn't guarantee that two consecutive calls will not contain duplicates; it guarantees that all elements chosen in one call won't.